# Re-Open Unity Asset store inside unity editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can Get the Unity asset store open inside the editor again?
I choosed to open it in the browser by mistake and I can't find how to get it back to open inside the editor
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From Unity versions 2020.1 onwards, the asset store is only available from the Asset Store website, but you can still import purchases using the Package Manager.

Even if you open the Asset Store tab again in the Unity Editor you are just greeted with this message.

[image: Unity Asset Store message]

There does not seem to be a way to bring this message back after checking the box to always open in the browser.

Comment: Yes, that's what I saw when I opened the Asset Store tab, thank you I appreciate your answer!